# Declaração de função em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Quais as diferenças em declarar uma função nessas duas maneiras:

**Modo 1**

```
var funcao = function() {
    // ...
};
```

**Modo 2**

```
function funcao() {
    // ...
}
```

Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de cada uma?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em termos práticos, a única diferença está em relação ao fluxo do código; se você tentar chamar uma função declarada pelo Modo 1 (`var funcao = function(...){...}`) antes desta linha ter sido executada, você receberá um erro de execução. O Modo 2, pelo contrário, garante que a função será encontrada mesmo antes da linha de sua declaração ter sido efetivamente executada.

Apenas para esclarecer, considere o exemplo abaixo:

```
var msg;
msg = msgSpan("Olá"); // Modo 2: ok
msg = msgNegrito("Mundo"); // Modo 1: Uncaught ReferenceError: msgNegrito is not defined 

function msgSpan(m){ return "<span>" + m + "</span>"; }
msgNegrito = function(m){ return "<span>" + m + "</span>"; }
```